# Convert multiline "tabular" string to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
name1                            pass  blue  n/a
name-6t56-yt6                    fail  red   n/a
name-45                          pass  blue  n/a
name-6t567-yt6                   fail  red   n/a
```

I want to extract data from the first 2 columns and would ideally store it in a dictionary in the following manner:

```
[{'type': 'name1', 'status': 'pass'}, {'type': 'name-6t56-yt6', 'status': 'fail'}, {'type': 'name-45', 'status': 'pass'}, {'type': 'name-6t567-yt6', 'status': 'fail'}]
```

Any ideas of how to approach this?

Note that this is a multi-line string(in utf-8 format).

Comment: Not even an attempt?

Comment: We need to know how the dict is supposed to look like

Comment: @timgeb I added the format in the post.

Comment: What is `entry`? Why is the key before the name sometimes `'type'` and sometimes `'name'`?

Comment: I edited the format to update the values. There should only be two keys 'type' and 'status'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a *list*:

Setup:

```
>>> s = '''name1                            pass  blue  n/a
... name-6t56-yt6                    fail  red   n/a
... name-45                          pass  blue  n/a
... name-6t567-yt6                   fail  red   n/a'''
```

Construct result:

```
>>> [dict(zip(('type', 'status'), line.split(maxsplit=2)[:2])) for line in s.splitlines()]
[{'type': 'name1', 'status': 'pass'}, {'type': 'name-6t56-yt6', 'status': 'fail'}, {'type': 'name-45', 'status': 'pass'}, {'type': 'name-6t567-yt6', 'status': 'fail'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using a set of dictionaries, it's not the best idea, here i am using a list of dictionaries

```
s = """name1                            pass  blue  n/a
name-6t56-yt6                    fail  red   n/a
name-45                          pass  blue  n/a
name-6t567-yt6                   fail  red   n/a"""

d = []
for line in s.split('\n'):
    type, status = line.split()[0:2]
    d.append({'type': type, 'status': status})
```

content of d:

```
[{'type': 'name1', 'status': 'pass'},
 {'type': 'name-6t56-yt6', 'status': 'fail'},
 {'type': 'name-45', 'status': 'pass'},
 {'type': 'name-6t567-yt6', 'status': 'fail'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

result = []
for line in data:
    result.append({
        'type': line[0:line.index(' ')],
        'status': 'pass' if 'pass' in line else 'fail'
    })

pprint(result)
# [{'status': 'pass', 'type': 'name1'},
#  {'status': 'fail', 'type': 'name-6t56-yt6'},
#  {'status': 'pass', 'type': 'name-45'},
#  {'status': 'fail', 'type': 'name-6t567-yt6'}]
```

Comment: what if the name contains the string 'pass' but the real status is fail

Answer (score 0):

With the text input defined as a multinine string, text, you can read it's content into the desired dictionary structure like this:

```
# from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint as pp

text = """name1                            pass  blue  n/a
name-6t56-yt6                    fail  red   n/a
name-45                          pass  blue  n/a
name-6t567-yt6                   fail  red   n/a"""

d = []
for line in text.split("\n"):
    type, status = line.split()[0:2]
    d.append({"type": type, "status": status})

pp(d)
```

Which will output:

```
[{'status': 'name1', 'type': 'pass'},
 {'status': 'name-6t56-yt6', 'type': 'fail'},
 {'status': 'name-45', 'type': 'pass'},
 {'status': 'name-6t567-yt6', 'type': 'fail'}]
```